# Draw label as a rectangle with edges rather than with rounded corners

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Using `geom_label()` in ggplot2, is it possible to make the rectangle perfectly square rather than with rounded corners?

```
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() + 
geom_label(x=4, y=7, label = "Test label")
```

I want to square up the rounded rectangle around Test label.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can set the `label.r` parameter to 0.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() +
  geom_label(x=4, y=7, label = "Test label",
             label.r = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @herbwilson please kindly consider marking this question as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers